# Youtube video is not working sometimes in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, xcode5

I have need a clarification for youtube video url imported in ios. My scenario is, i created a tableview, when i click the cell it will navigate to my Detailviewcontroller. In detailviewcontroller page i had one UIButton, when i click that button, it will play a video. this video url contains youtube video url. It is worked fine at before 3 days. now it not working. I don't know what mistake i had in my code.

My Code is :
DetailViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)YouTube:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    PlayViewController *PVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayViewController"];
    PVC.videourl=strVideoURL;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:PVC animated:YES];
}
```

PlayViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *arr=[YoutubeParser parseHTML:videourl];
    NSString *myArrayString = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:myArrayString];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
    NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}
```

Comment: use UIWebView to play youtube videos, then you won't face those problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Answers by myself. here i used older version of XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController for playing videos. now i downloaded the new file from here https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController. now issue is solved.